# Getting the parameters of a generic function in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm dealing with a generic React functional component that doesn't export its prop interface:

```js
interface ComponentProps<T> {
    test: T;
}

export function Component<T>(props: ComponentProps<T>): React.ReactElement;
```

I would like to build a component that extends that component:

```js
interface MyComponentProps<T> extends ComponentProps<T> {
    another: string;
}

function MyComponent<T>({ another, ...props }: MyComponentProps<T>): React.ReactElement {
    return <Component {...props}/>;
}
```

The problem is that I need to get access to the `ComponentProps` interface, which is not exported. Normally I can do it like this:

```js
type ComponentProps = Parameters<typeof Component>[0];
```

but in this case, I need to somehow specify the generic:

```js
type ComponentProps<T> = Parameters<typeof Component<T>>[0]; // Error
```

Is there any way how I can get access to the generic interface?